# How to extract the content of this element?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract `<div class="ex_example"> aa </div> <div class="ex_example"> aa </div>`

from :

```
    <div class="c-w">
      <div class="c-s">
        <div class="ex_example"> aa </div>
        <div class="ex_example"> aa </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

with below code :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''
<div class="c-w">
  <div class="c-s">
    <div class="ex_example"> aa </div>
    <div class="ex_example"> aa </div>
  </div>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')
soup.select('.c-w .c-s')[0].contents
```

Unfortunately, the output is not as expected,

```
['\n',
 <div class="ex_example"> aa </div>,
 '\n',
 <div class="ex_example"> aa </div>,
 '\n']
```

Could you please modify my code to achieve my goal? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will find all the children in your selected tag:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''
<div class="c-w">
  <div class="c-s">
    <div class="ex_example"> aa </div>
    <div class="ex_example"> aa </div>
  </div>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')
soup.select('.c-w .c-s')[0].findAll()
```

If there is no filtering parameters, `findAll()` will return all children.

Edit: To get the children as a string, you can join them together:

```
''.join(map(str, soup.select('.c-w .c-s')[0].findAll()))
```

or

```
''.join([str(child) for child in soup.select('.c-w .c-s')[0].findAll()])
```

Comment: Your code returns a list. I would like to ask if it's possible to get  `<div class="ex_example"> aa </div> <div class="ex_example"> aa </div>`, not just `[<div class="ex_example"> aa </div>, <div class="ex_example"> aa </div>]`.

Comment: In that case you can create strings from the children and join them together. Edited my answer.